# how to display the UTC Current Hour in power apps?

Tags: powerapps

how to display the UTC Current Hour in power apps,

I tried this function "`Hour(UTCNow())`" but is not working on PowerApps.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression for that:

```
Hour(DateAdd(Now(), TimeZoneOffset(Now()), TimeUnit.Minutes))
```

Adding TimeZoneOffset(dateTime) minutes to a dateTime value will "bring it to UTC". At that point you can use the Hour function to retrieve it.

Comment: No, it did not work, this one is for system time like Now().

what I need is to display UTC Current Hour, whatever your local time is

Comment: Can you give an example of what you get when you have labels with the following expressions in your app? `Now()`; `TimeZoneOffset(Now())`; `DateAdd(Now(), TimeZoneOffset(Now()), TimeUnit.Minutes)`? And what is the time zone in your system?